# Which : \only or \onslide ? (Beamer)

Tags: beamer, overlays

In [`beamer` v3.0 guide](http://saikat.guha.cc/ref/beamer_guide.pdf) (slide 121) , I've found:

> In case of subtle differences in the heights of replacements,
>   `overlayarea` and `overprint` environments can be used.

But it's not clear to me.

What are differences between `\only` and `\onslide` in Beamer ?

How to decide, which to choose in particular case?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

In short, `\only<>{}` does not render the braced material *at all* except on the named slides, while `\onslide<>` renders the material *until the next `\onslide`*, sort of like an `\item`, but, on the off slides, covers it (according to the preference given in `\setbeamercovered`; i.e. transparent or invisible).  There are other alternatives, for example, `\uncover<>{}`, which functions like `\only` but acts like `\onslide`; i.e. takes a specific chunk of text and covers or uncovers it as appropriate.

There are some circumstances where they work differently.  For example, using `\onslide` in one of the `amsmath` equation environments (I have found) produces horrible bugs:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
...
\begin{align*}
 a & \onslide<+-> b % Bad
 a & \uncover<+->{b}% Good
\end{align*}
```

Presumably this is because `align` does what the manual calls "wicked things" in processing its contents.

You also ask about the `overlayarea` and `overprint` environments; these are fancy versions of `\uncover` and `\onslide` respectively, that reserve the space for an entire sequence of uncoverings.  The `overprint` environment does so automatically but only allows you to uncover in an "itemized" fashion by using `\onslide` successively, and the `overlayarea` environment requires you to say exactly the size of the overlay area but allows you to use any Beamer constructs inside; it will then produce the requisite number of slides with various material appearing in that area (including necessary empty space) on each one.

Comment: Why are there 4 ways to write same thing-- `\only`, `\onslide`, `\uncover`, `\visible` ? (are there instances where onslide works but others fail?)

Comment: one can use aligned instead of align

Comment: @CyriacAntony The principle difference is between commands like `\only` that only render the content _at all_ on the specified slides, vs commands like `\uncover` that always render the content but only make it _visible_ on the specified slides.  Can make a big difference to layout, especially if for some reason reveals are occurring in "the wrong order".  The other differences are more subtle imo.